# Bootstrap How to make a responsive grid degradating in two steps?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I previously worked with yaml css framework where elements are degradating in two or more steps and now I've got to translate this somehow to a bootstrap 2.3x based wp-theme. But the responsiveness seems to be only in one step so I really don't know how to make it work for me. Please help me.

[I've got a jsfiddle for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jq5m/1/)

**Update** I just updated to 3.x bootstrap. I hope this would make a solution possible...

The code:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="padding:1em;margin-top:3em;">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4"> <a class='' href='#'>
                    <img class='media-object medium' src='http://dummyimage.com/160x250/ccc/222.png' id=''>
                </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="span8">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">author</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright"><a>Some Author</a></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Title</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">The Earth within</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Serial</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">Keine / Einzelroman</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Publisher</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">Bookmonsters </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Published in</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">2011-01-24</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Info</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">asdfasfd</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you able to upgrade to bootstrap 3?

Comment: No, unfortunately not - this would break the webpage. Would this make a difference?

Comment: @able-alias I upgradet to bootstrap 3 - what now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've upgrade to Bootstrap 3, you shouldn't need custom CSS. You can just use the `md` and `xs` classes...

### http://www.bootply.com/117713

```
<div class="row" style="padding:1em;margin-top:3em;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">
                   <a class="" href="#">
                    <img class="media-object medium img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/160x250/ccc/222.png" id="">
                   </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">author</span>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-left text-bright"><a>Some Author</a></span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">Title</span>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">The Earth within</span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">Serial</span>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">Keine / Einzelroman</span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">Publisher</span>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">Bookmonsters </span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">Published in</span>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">2011-01-24</span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right">Info</span>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">asdfasfd</span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.
                </div>
          </div><!--/row-->
     </div><!--/col-12-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: Personally I think your answer is best for now using BS3. +1

Answer (score 2):

You will have to override `bootstrap's` default styling in order to make your example work. Use the `CSS` below as your start point:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .override [class*=span] {
        float: left;
    }

    .override .span4 {
        width: 30%;        
    }

    .override .span8 {
        width: 70%;        
    }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jq5m/4/)

Comment: This is not working for me. But many thanks for trying helping me = plus one. But as you commented above Skelly got the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is **[This](http://www.bootply.com/118038)** what you are trying to achieve ? Assuming you are using bootstrap 3

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" class="pull-right">  
</div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">author</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright"><a>Some Author</a></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Title</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">The Earth within</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Serial</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">Keine / Einzelroman</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Publisher</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">Bookmonsters </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Published in</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">2011-01-24</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="pull-right">Info</span>
                                </td>
                                <td><span class="pull-left text-bright">asdfasfd</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
</div>
      <div class="col-md-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't doing anything I'm looking for. This shows a static layout and I wanted degradation from 3 to two columns.

Comment: use col-sm for tablets and col-xs for smaller resolutions. I am assuming here that you know what are these classes for.